# What is the best way to show the monotonicity of this recursive sequence?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, induction

This is the sequence:

$a_{n+1}$ = $\sqrt{3a_{n} - 2}$
$a_{0}$ = 3

Before evaluating monotonicity I know that the sequence is converting towards either 1 or 2.

My approach is to assume it is monotonously decreasing and then:

1. (observed) $a_{0} = 3 \geq \sqrt{7} = a_{1}$
2. (assumed) $a_{n} \geq a_{n+1}$
3. (hyptothetised)  $a_{n+1} \geq a_{n+2}$

from 2. i can say

$\Rightarrow3a_{n} \geq 3a_{n+1}$

$\Rightarrow3a_{n} - 2 \geq 3a_{n+1} - 2$

$\Rightarrow\sqrt{3a_{n} - 2} \geq \sqrt{3a_{n+1} - 2}$

(i think i can take the square root if i know that it converges to either 1 or 2, correct?)

$\Rightarrow a_{n+1} \geq a_{n+2}$

Can i do it like this? If yes, is it conclusive/ is there a better way or a good alternative? If no, what is the right approach?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
Since most of the answers address the boundedness of the sequence, i should add this (sorry if it comes late):
I made the assumption that for $lim(n\rightarrow\infty)$ that $a_{n} = a_{n+1}$ and arrive at

$(a_{n=\infty} - 2)(a_{n=\infty} - 1) = 0$

So i know the limit is either 1 or 2, right? Since in both cases $3a_{n} -2 > 0$, would this be enough to make my proof of monotonicity (above) valid? Or is this argument again circular?

Comment: You have given most of the details of a proof by induction that the sequence is decreasing.  But before you have proved monotonicity (and boundedness below, which you have not even mentioned) you cannot assert that the limit exists.

Comment: Your boundedness argument is circular, since you assume that the sequence has a limit, while that is exactly what you want to conclude in the end. See the answer by @RRL for the rescue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $a_0 =3$, then by induction $a_n > 2$ for all $n$:

$$a_{n-1} > 2 \implies 3a_{n-1}-2 > 4 \implies a_{n} =\sqrt{3a_{n-1}-2} > 2$$

Hence, your proof of monotonicity is valid (you can take the square root).

Now you have a decreasing sequence bounded below, which must converge.

Comment: OK, sorry for my comment, I now see what your argument actually is about.

Comment: great answer, so with this line added I both have validated the monotonicity proof and have shown what the lower bound is, correct?

Comment: @djun: Thanks.  That is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You get a typo there...It is $a_{0} = 3 \geq \sqrt{7} = a_{1}$. ;)

You can not take square root directly, since you haven't proven it converges. Yes, you know the final answer... but a rigor proof can't use anything you didn't prove, or it will be circular argument.

So you may prove that $a_n>0$ first. But here is a tricky thing: $a_n>0$ is not enough to say $a_{n+1}>0$. So as you observed, you may prove $a_n \geq 1$, by induction.

Then you can use the square root idea.